# Entity Framework: insert an object with a foreign key which is already known, but doesn't exist in DB yet

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework and would like to insert an object into the database that references another object that doesn't exist in the DB yet (but the foreign key is known already).

Simple example: assume I have two tables, `Books` (identified by their ISBN) and `Purchases`. I'd like to be able to insert purchases, even if the book hasn't been set up in the DB yet:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public virtual string ISBN { get; set; }

    protected virtual IEnumerable<Purchase> purchases { get; set; }

    public virtual string author { get; set; }
    public virtual string title { get; set; }
// .....
}

public class Purchase
{
    [Key]
    protected virtual int id { get; set; }

    public virtual Book book { get; set; }

    public virtual double price;
}
```

Conceptually, this would be easy: the `Purchase` table will have a foreign key that is the book's ISBN. So in regular SQL, I could just insert the ISBN into this field, and add the book to the books table sometime later.

In EF/C# though, I can't think of an easy way to do this. The `Purchase` class references the `Book` class, so I can't just use the ID (ISBN) directly here.

What I could do is create a dummy book object and use this to insert the purchase. Problem is that Entity Framework automatically inserts the dummy book object into the table too, which I want to avoid:

```
var dummyBook = new Book();
dummyBook.isbn = "978-0141354217";

var purchase = new Purchase();
purchase.price = 99.95;
purchase.book = dummyBook;

dbContext.Purchases.Add(purchase);

// Should add the purchase to the DB, but NOT the book!
// Unfortunately, EF adds both automatically...
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: remove the `public virtual Book book { get; set; }` from `Purchase` and just have a string column `ISBN`

Comment: Why can't you just leave it be, then just update the Book record when you wish to add it? This is how foreign key should work http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

Comment: You could map a foreign key property on your Purchase class if you want to set the DB foreign key by ISBN number, however if there is no book record in the DB with that ISBN as it's primary key it will fail the referential integrity check when you insert it into the database. Why do you want to insert what is essentially invalid data?

Comment: Why can't you create the book record first?

Comment: I think you're approaching the problem in the wrong way. Is a book required for a purchase? Then don't add a purchase until you have a book. "Dummy data" should not be acceptable. If a book isn't required for a purchase then insert the purchase without a book attached.

Comment: Answering your question: all you need to have is a nullable FK on a purchase so you can fill it up later. Although according to some sources it's not recommended approach.

Comment: Why do you and a reference to a book and don't want to save the book to the DB? you need to put ISBN on the purchase or add the book to the DB there is no other way.

Comment: AlexanderBrevig: That is possible yes, but causes some other problems:
E.g. I can't simply use DbContext.AddRange(purchases) when several purchases refer to the same book, as it'll try to insert one and the same book many times (-> duplicate primary key).
Also I'll need to reliably track which objects in the DB are dummies, and which ones are properly initialized but may just contain null values by intention; possibly with an extra field.

Both issues are managable, but I hoped there might be a nicer solution. Will keep considering this one though, thanks!

Comment: neurotix: Unfortunately, when there are many purchases in the database with null foreign keys, I won't be able to identify later on which ones belonged to which books anymore, so there's no way for me to update afterwards anymore.

Comment: Shoe: The book/purchase thing was an example to keep it brief. In my system, raw data (purchases) is only available for a few minutes and then lost forever, while the descriptive data (books) needs to be entered manually once a week or so. If I require the "books" to be entered first, I'll lose a lot of "purchase" data unless I develop a second storage method for those cases (very very inconvenient)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite the fact that ISBN is (should be) unique and seems like a good candidate for a primary key, it's never a good practice to use any natural key as a primary key in the database.

Details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key

So, once the ISBN is not your primary key, but just a string field, you'll be able to do what you want: insert a purchase for a particular ISBN without having the book record. In this case you wouldn't have `virtual Book` property of the `Purchase` class. You could replace it with a something like this:

```
public Book GetBook (string isbn, DbContext context)
{
    return context.Books.Where(x => x.ISBN == isbn).FirstOrDefaul();
}
```

All this without going into discussion why you'd have a purchase of a book that doesn't exist in the DB.

Comment: Hi, very helpful input - thanks!
The books/purchases were just an example to keep it simple&brief, assume there is a good reason for the whole "purchases before book" weirdness.

I wanted to use the "isbn" for easy direct readability of the database file, but you're right of course I could use a different key and store the isbn as a regular field.

That suggestion would somewhat break the usual EF navigation mechanism though, not sure if that might cause problems - E.g. significantly worse performance, no integrated error checks (uniqueness) etc.?

Comment: This will not influence the performance in any way. Navigation properties are there for convenience in specifying relations between entities and later for accessing them from your code. For the uniqueness, you can specify using EF fluent API that property `Book.ISBN` has unique value, which would translate into creating an appropriate DB constraint - again no performance impact.

Comment: Thanks again! There is one last - but significant - follow up problem with this. Your answer would be the best way to go (and I'll mark it as the answer) if that last issue is solvable.

Described here, as this is a problem on its own- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864735/entity-framework-faking-a-queryable-navigation-property