# Entity Framework: "Faking" a queryable navigation property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'd like to "fake" a navigation property in an EF-mapped class.

Consider an example where I have books (identified by "isbn") and purchases (identified by "isbn" too) - note that Books and Purchases are intentionally NOT directly mapped to each other.

Now I'd like to create an extension method for "Book" that returns all purchases of the book in a queryable format, something like

```
public class Book
{
    public virtual string isbn { get; set; }
    public virtual string name { get; set; }


    // Pseudo-code .. does not work, throws an exception
    // "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method [...], and this method cannot
    // be translated into a store expression
    public virtual IQueryable<Purchase> get_purchases(DbContext context)
    {
        return context.Purchases.Where(purchase => purchase.isbn == this.isbn);
    }
}

public class Purchase
{
    public virtual string isbn { get; set; }
    public virtual double price { get; set; }
}
```

So in the end, I'd like to do any arbitrary queries such as (completely random example)

```
dbContext.Books.Where(book => book.get_purchases(dbContext).Where(purchase => purchase.price > 90))
```

But as mentioned in the comment, my approach doesn't work, as EF / LINQ can't make use of my extension method.

Is there any way to do this?
The statement should be translateable into a single SQL query; I don't want to use any methods like .ToList() to avoid retreiving unnecessarily huge datasets.

Could this work by creating a function that returns an

```
Expression<Func<Book, IQueryable<Purchase>>>
```

or anything of that kind? (Couldn't try this yet as I am absolutely horrible at writing expressions), or is there any other approach?

Disclaimer: There is a good reason to not explicitly map Purchases <-> Bonds; shouldn't be relevant to the question, but the background is based on Floremin's answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846318/entity-framework-insert-an-object-with-a-foreign-key-which-is-already-known-bu)

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you may have over-interpreted the answer on your other question. The fact that you should not use an isbn as primary key doesn't mean that you can't have a relationship. It should just be based on a surrogate key, like an autoincremented (IDENTITY) int field (Id, for example). Than you could have a relationship between books and purchases. And no need to have isbn in purchase entity.

Comment: Hi, the main issue was actually that I will at times need to insert purchases for an ISBN for which no entry may exist in the Books-table yet (but will later at some point). So no matter what primary key to use, if I go down that path, it'd mean having some temporary null-references, including additional/duplicate fields into the table and manually updating null references in the table every now and then - so a solution that unfortunately comes with its own additional issues and complexities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ to entities translates LINQ queries into SQL queries which are then sent and executed in the database (server). That's why you get the exception that your `get_purchases` method cannot be translated into store expression (SQL).

To get books that were paid more than 90 you can use LINQ Join operator:

```
var books = from b in dBContext.Books
            join p in dBContext.Purchases on b.isbn equals p.isbn
            where p.price > 90
            select b;
```

Here is a great LINQ resource: [LINQ 101](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b/viewsamplepack)

If you want to have EF-like navigation properties like `Book.Purchases` where there is no actual relation in the database, you'd have to create your own data repository layer that would be initialized with the `DbContext` which would be used in all properties and methods. Then you would be using that for all data access - i.e. you'd never use `DbContext` directly in your code. This is a good practice on larger projects, especially if you need to implement some business rules and data manipulation before it gets stored in the database. Look up "repository pattern" and you're sure to find many resources.

Here's one: [Using the Repository Pattern with ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-the-repository-pattern-with-asp.net-mvc-and-entity-framework.htm)

Comment: Repositories are something I originalled wanted to avoid, as the project is rather small scale; but I'm indeed going with this option right now (in combination with entities that are not directly mapped with Navigation properties), as that pattern allows most control. I do have to create quite a load of specific repository methods unfortunately, but that's busywork in the end, and will at least keep the solution "clean" and to a decent code standard. Thanks for your input!